# Xcode write file to plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I write to a plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116179/how-can-i-write-to-a-plist-file)

how can i setobject to myPlist by search to NSUserDomainMask? i need to tap a save button to save a text in plist which is stored locally inside my app sandbox.thanks if there is any sample code or tutorial,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

//file(NSArray or NSDictionary) is the file to be saved in the data.plist

-(IBAction) saveFile:(id) sender{

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath 
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
[file writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES]; 

}
```

Comment: any idea on this code?
`
-(NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myList.plist"];
dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    return dictionary;
}
`

Comment: NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
    [dictionary setObject:number forKey:@"key3"];
    

    for (id key in dictionary) {
        NSLog(@"web key=%@, value=%@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
        
        [dictionary writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

Comment: @user1049312 My code will search the path of your document directory.. then appending the file name with the document dir path...will give the path of the file...after then writting the file on that path.