# Multiple objects into plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to add multiple objects to a plist, from the same UITextField.
I explain better. I have an UITextField from which I add a phone number to a plist. The problem is that I can't add more than one number to that plist from only one textfield.
This is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;

NSArray *theArray;

theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textField.text, nil];

myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[myDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:addedTime];


NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PhoneNumbers" ofType:@"plist"];
[myDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Is there any way to fix the problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a little further what you're trying to do?  In particular, how are the phone numbers separated and how do you want them represented in the plist?  As it stands, you read a single string value from the text field and store it as a dictionary containing a single text object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to write to Plist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116831/not-able-to-write-to-plist) **and** [of this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116179/how-can-i-write-to-a-plist-file) **and** [and of this question as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193912/strange-problem-with-reading-and-writing-a-plist-file), I can't imagine why it's so hard to search for this...

Comment: I can write to the plist, that's not the problem. The problem is that I write what's in the textfield, but seems I can only add one item to the plist. If I add one more, it overwrites the first one. Do you understand ?

Comment: @H2CO3 The specific question is not a dupe.  However, OP should read those questions for details on other issues.

Answer (score 2):

`writeToFile:atomically:` completely replaces whatever is on disk with the contents of the object you to call `writeToFile:atomically:` on.

If you want to append to whatever is on disk, you'll need to load it first, add to the dictionary, then write the whole thing back.

Note that you should *never write anything to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`*.  In fact, you can't on a device at all in a production build.